# Copy Last Value in a column matching with another value in different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

First time here, but cannot work this one out.

I'm trying to find the last value in a column relating to another column

**Sheet 2**
column B has vehicle registrations (repeated multiple time) e.g 1kmt499
column F has vehicle mileage

```
column B column F  
-------- ---------  
1kmt499  45
1kmt499  302
1kmt499  627
1kmt499  805
9999999  37
9999999  950
```

**Sheet 1** - dashboard

If 1kmt499 is selected or entered, I need to know the last update mileage from sheet 2 for registration number 1kmt499 which would be 805.

A1 = 1kmt499 B2 = 805

Thanks for your help in advance

Cheers

Comment: It's not quite clear how your initial data looks. Please clarify this. And: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Post your code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Call a sub like this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    FindMileage "1kmt499"
End Sub
```

Have a sub look at each row with that registration and check for the highest mileage.

```
Private Sub FindMileage(strRegistration As String)

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim lMilage As Long
    Dim c As Variant

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With ws2.Range("b1:b" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.count)
        Set c = .Find(strRegistration, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                'Is this the current registration?
                If c.Value = strRegistration Then
                    'Is this mileage higher than the other rows we have checked?
                    If ws2.Range("F" & c.Row) > lMilage Then
                        'Yes, record it.
                        lMilage = ws2.Range("F" & c.Row)
                    End If
                End If
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With

    'Write the values to sheet 1
    ws.Range("A1").Value = strRegistration
    ws.Range("B1").Value = lMilage

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If `A1` of your Sheet1 contains the value to search for, e.g. `1kmt499`, then:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$F$1:$F$999,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$999,0)+COUNTIF(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$999,A1)-1)
```

will return the last corresponding vehicle mileage. The `MATCH` function finds the first row containing the target value, the `COUNTIF` function finds how many rows there are with this value, and the `INDEX` function looks up the corresponding result. I've assumed that the registration and mileage table occupies rows 1 to 999, change this as appropriate.

**Note** this assumes that each vehicle registration only appears in one contiguous repeated block, as per your question - if in fact your data could have some entries for `1kmt499`, then some for `9999999`, then some more for `1kmt499`, this won't work.

It also assumes that by 'the last' value, you mean the one furthest down the spreadsheet - not necessarily the largest mileage value, if these aren't in ascending order.

Comment: This formula will work provided that the `Countif` part `COUNTIF(A1,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$999)` is changed to `COUNTIF(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$999,A1)`